# raty star rating plugin for storing data from multiple ratings

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am using the raty star rating jQuery plugin from this site : http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty/ by Washington Botelho.
I am using multiple ratings in my single form. The different ratings are like this :

```
<div id='star1' class='star'></div>
<input name='score1' type='hidden' id='score-target' />

<div id='star2' class='star'></div>
<input name='score2' type='hidden' id='score-target' />

<div id='star3' class='star'></div>
<input name='score3' type='hidden' id='score-target' />
```

Now i am not much familiar with jQuery, but i tried a lot to go through and understand its js files. I wrote the javascript code like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $('.star').raty({
            cancel      : true,
            targetKeep  : true,
            targetType  : 'number',
            targetText  : '0',
            target      : '#score-target'
            });

            $('#score').raty({
                score: function() {
                    return $(this).attr('data-rating');
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that only the score from the last rating is getting stored in my inputs, the first 2 inputs are storing null values. Im not using Ajax as i am not familiar with it. I am using php to get the data from the form and then storing it in a table. Can anyone help me with the javascript code to store the different values in the different hiddne input fields?

Comment: all 3 inputs have the same id, thats your problem

Comment: @Nick yes i know that... but the documentation of the plugin says u can store the rating score in a vessel with id which is `target: "#score-target"` and since all the ratings fall in the same class, i need to find out a way to store different values in different vessels

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your code and observe src attribute of "on-stars" For me ,  src attribute of on-stars"  contains star-on .

```
        score: function() {
            return $('img[src*="star-on"]',$(this)).length;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem is here :

```
target      : '#score-target'
```

You're using the selector `#` it mean an **ID** nammed 'score-target'.
In html an **ID** is unique That's why it return everytime the 1st reference of this id.

You should write sth like this :

```
<div id='star1' class='star' rel="score-target1"></div>
<input name='score1' type='hidden' id='score-target1' />
...


...
target      : $(this).attr('rel')
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But did you actually see the plugin and saw its code by yourself ?

Comment: btw, it didn't helped in solving the problem :(